# The definition of a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Compactness: A set $K \subseteq R$ is compact if every sequence in K has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in K

This is the definition of a compact set. I do not understand this definition and how you have to use it to prove a set is compact.

1. The main point i do not understand is what "a subsequence" means. And how it converges to a limit.
2. The second is, it has to hold for every sequence is there not a randomly weird sequence that just changes a lot. Then i cannot find a limit? Even harder the limit of the subsequence?

So these are multiple questions. Not just one.

Comment: You need to read the definition of subsequence.

Comment: It looks like your second question is asking why is it the case that if a sequence is convergent, any subsequence must converge to the same limit.  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I read it as "How would I know that there isn't some random, wildly chaotic sequence that jdoes not have a limit. How can one hope to find the limit of a subsequence?"

Comment: @Arthur rereading it, that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel you might find it more intuitive to think of this way: given a weird sequence, we're picking out a convergent subspaces using the fact that the sequence will eventually have to fall in "the same area" twice.  If you only look at the elements that fall into a certain area, then you end up with a subsequence

Comment: "I do not understand this definition and how you have to use it to prove a set is compact." Well, if sequential compactness IS your definition of compactness (which by the way is valid for arbitrary topological spaces), then there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1):

1. A subset is to a set as a subsequence is to a sequence. The only extra requirement that we impose on a subsequence is that its terms are in the same order as in the original sequence. For example, for a sequence $$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\ldots,$$ a subsequence might be $$a_1,a_4,a_9,a_{16},a_{25},\ldots,$$ but neither $$a_2,a_1,a_3,a_4,a_7,\ldots$$ nor $$a_1,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_5,\ldots$$ would be valid.
2. This has to hold for every sequence. However, this is somewhat easier that might seem at first glance. For example, by [Bolzano-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), **every** bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^n$, no matter how weird it might seem, has a convergent subsequence. I’d recommend you read the proof on the article. That might give some more context on the kinds of things compactness can imply.